# Reorder rows by predetermined strings in R

Tags: r

I know this is a simple question so I apologize in advance.

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
| name  | count | class       |
|-------|-------|-------------|
| bob   | 1     | first grade |
| adam  | 5     | college     |
| suzie | 7     | high school |
```

and I want to reorder the rows by class, as in:

```
| name  | count | class       |
|-------|-------|-------------|
| bob   | 1     | first grade |
| suzie | 7     | high school |
| adam  | 5     | college     |
```

I can't use `order()` since I don't want the class reordered alphabetically.

I tried this, but it failed:

```
target <- c("first grade", "high school", "college")
df[match(target, df$class),]
```

This should be straightforward...but reordering is usually reserved for when the values in the columns have some sort of alphanumeric structure. Here, the structure is to be defined by me.

I suppose I could append a new column, with number assignments for class, then sort by that. But there has got to be a more graceful way??

Answer (score 2):

Make `class` a `factor` with the levels in the order you want, then use `order()`.

```
df$class = factor(df$class, levels = target)
df[order(df$class), ]
```

Comment: or don't convert the column: `df[order(factor(df$class, levels = target)),]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this via an ordered factor.
First create a factor variable from your variable of interest

```
d <- df$class
```

Then order the factor by the order you wish

```
x <- ordered(factor(d), levels=c('first grade','high school','college'))
```

Then use this to order your df

```
df[order(x),]
```

Job done, go play a board game.

Comment: You don't need an `ordered` factor for the levels to have an order. Even regular factors have levels in the order you specify. `ordered` factors are only needed when you want contrasts in a model to be 2v1, 3v2, 4v3 instead of the usual 2v1, 3v1, 4v1, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Gregor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `match` needs to be modified a little to work:

```
df[order(match(df$class, target)),]
```